# Record at 720p on Lenovo Tab4 8

Tags: android, camera, resolution, tablet, preview

I have a running video app that is solidly recording videos in 1280x720 for many android tablets running 7.0 and higher except for the Lenovo Tab4 8.

Using the Camera2 API I setup the capturing by querying the supported preview sizes.
The Lenovo Tab4 8 suprisingly only returns these Preview Sizes:

> 1040x780, 864x480, 640x640, 800x480, 720x480, 768x432, 640x480,
>   480x640, 576x432, 640x360, 480x360, 480x320, 384x288, 352x288,
>   320x240, 240x320, 240x160, 176x144, 144x176, 160x120

But the built in camera supports 1280x720 even 1920x1080. Simply trying to set the resolution or the preview size to 1280x720 ends up with an error. `android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): submitRequestList - must configure  device with valid surfaces before submitting requests`

How come other camera apps can handle it? I downloaded "Open Camera" from the playstore. It has the option to capture at 1280x720 (but not 1040x780?!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out whats causing this.
This Lenovo tablet has a "legacy camera", meaning the Camera was created to serve the Camera API but not the Camera2 API.

Camera2 API in this case is just a wrapper of the Camera API but it cannot expose every functionality and is therefore missing support for certain resolutions.

With the following calls I can now find out, whether my device inhabits a legacy camera:

Xamarin.Android:

```
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = camManager.GetCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
var hardwareLevel = characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.InfoSupportedHardwareLevel);

//hardwareLevel.ToString() would spit out one of the following numbers:
//LEGACY - 2 -> Legacy Cameras might not support 1280x720 resolution
//LIMITED - 0
//FULL - 1
//LEVEL_3 - 3
```